# Exporting string in bash

Tags: bash, cat, crypt

I would like to export an encrypted string to a file that already has some content.

How can i delete the content of this file and add my string?

I tried cat but that did not work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bash you can easily redirect a string into a file with bash like this

```
echo "This is my string" > filename
```

A single `>` will replace the contents, `>>` will append the string to the end of the file.

For more information have a look at the [bash manual regarding Redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections).

Answer (score 0):

Use the > redirection operator, it will wipe out the target file.  Use the >> to append to the end of the target file

```
cat encrypted_file.txt > desired_file.txt
```

Comment: I think i neet to add some more information. I got a config-file to save username and password. Now i use a .sh to read the Logindata. I use an encryption command to encrypt my passwd variable. Now i want to export the declared variables as strings to the existing config-file. In case of existing content i would like to replace the old content with the new one. I hope you understand my broken english.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach :

```
 while read user pass;do 
    echo "$user,$pass"
    # do encrypt or other operation before echo 
  done <configfile >configfile.new
```